# Is it possibile to pass an Activity to a non activity class?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I read many posts (one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880657/best-practice-to-pass-context-to-non-activity-classes)) and articles according to which you shouldn't pass `context` from an `Activity` to a non activity class, to avoid leak of memory.

I have to use the method `findViewById()` in a non activity class.
So far,I did this:

```
    public class Text{

        Activity activity;

        public Text(Activity activity){
           this.activity = activity;
        }

        public TextView getMyTextView(){
           return activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        }

    }
```

Now I'm wondering if even "passing" an `Activity` can lead to a memory leak.
What's the best way to be able to call, for example, the method `findViewById` in a non activity class.

Comment: Why pass the Activity and not the TextView? Why even pass any view? The databinding library would map a String directly into a TextView without findViewById

Comment: Even tho I don't see the purpose of such thing, I would recommend to wrap your activity in a weakReference. So when the activity is destroyed you'll get a null value, ofc you need to check if it's null every time you make use of that ref but it'll make sure you're not leaking anything.

Comment: Thank everybody for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing which can lead to memory leak is misunderstanding of how GC works. The basic rule of avoiding memory leak is to make sure that objects which should be collected by `GC` are disconnected from `GC Root`:

[image]

There're set of GC roots, and one of them is static field. So, if you assign your activity to such field then GC could not collect it:

```
class ActivityRef {

 public static Activity ref;

 public static void setActivity(Activity activity){
    ActivityRef.ref = activity;
 }
}
```

And this activity(with all views, bitmaps and all connected objects) will remain in memory until the app is not killed by system.

Another GC root is `Thread`.

```
class SomeThread extends Thread{

  Activity ref;

  public void setActivity(Activity activity){
    this.ref = activity;
  }
}
```

While thread is alive GC can't collect activity instance.

Therefore there is no best way or method to call `findViewById` which allows you to avoid memory leak, there is memory model which describes how GC works, if you follow these rules you will never have memory leaks. More [here](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/).

Good articles about WeakReferences:

- [You don’t have to use WeakReference to avoid memory leaks](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/weakreference-in-android-dd1e66b9be9d#.vf9ttyrs7)
- [Finally understanding how references work in Android and Java](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83#.a6ih32onn)

Comment: Better to use a weak reference to an Activity class

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think so. WeakReferences just spoil the code with null checks and extra logic. Here good thoughts about WeakReferences: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/weakreference-in-android-dd1e66b9be9d#.8nk16vpoo https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83#.gry925pel

Comment: Perhaps, but I've read posts like don't store Activity references in Asynctask, for example. Just seems like a bad design to need a UI element from a model / utility class

Comment: Thank everybody for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather then passing the activity reference pass it the views that are necessary. Make sure that the "Non-Activity" class reference is created after your activity class is invoked and release the reference (nonActivityReference = null) before destroying your activity.

Comment: Thank everybody for the help :)